# Is the decrease in vaccine uptake in the US for two weeks in a row in line with some models' expectation?

Tags: covid-19, vaccination, public-health, united-states

According to Reuters news of May 3, vaccinations have also fallen in the US [for two weeks in a row](https://www.reuters.com/world/us/new-us-covid-cases-fall-third-week-deaths-lowest-since-july-2021-05-03/).

> Nationally, deaths from COVID-19 fell 3% to 4,819 in the week ended May 2, the fewest deaths in a week since July.
>
> The average number of COVID-19 patients in hospitals fell 8%, the first weekly decrease after rising or holding steady for four weeks.
>
> **Vaccinations fell for a second week in a row, dropping 12% after falling 14% in the previous week.**

According to what Google captures from Our World in Data, the US seems to be approaching the middle point on Covid-19 vaccines uptake :

> [image]

And in more (textual) [detail](https://www.theguardian.com/us-news/2021/may/02/us-covid-vaccinations-clinics-outreach-campaigns-vaccine-hesitancy):

> in the last two weeks daily vaccination rates in the US have peaked and declined from a high of 3.2m daily vaccine administrations per day to 2.5m. Now, health authorities nationally are experiencing what red states such as Mississippi and Wyoming began to see early signs of – a major slowdown.
>
> The phenomenon is repeated across the country. Local authorities in Los Angeles, California; Colorado; Florida; Nevada and Texas are poised to close mass vaccination sites by the end of May. Georgia has already decided to shut down all of its mass vaccination sites by the end of May, citing lack of demand. The state is far behind the nation in terms of administering vaccines, with 34% of the population having received at least one dose, compared with 43% nationally. [...]
>
> Data from the CDC shows states across the south and west have the highest levels of vaccine hesitancy, and uptake is notably low across these states.  [...]

There exist various kinds of models of vaccine uptake over time, some more sophisticated than others.
E.g. [some](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/17056073/) take into account the disease spread as modulating
the personal risk estimation in deriving temporal dynamics of vaccine demand, which may be
convergent or even unstable/oscillating--the latter may happen if demand is very sensitive to the disease spread. (Most models in this area seem just to derive an [equilibrium point](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2950864) in the most tractable/stable scenarios. Such models have been applied to influenza vaccine uptake in the US, [for example](https://www.pnas.org/content/104/13/5692).)

Basically, have any such temporal models of vaccine uptake been applied to Covid-19 vaccination in the US? And if so, did/do they reasonably predict the currently observed uptake data?

Comment: Expected in view of *what*? What are "some models"?

Comment: @BryanKrause: in view of what models predict vaccine uptake might look like over time. I can definitely find some such models for some countries https://www.medrxiv.org/content/10.1101/2020.12.17.20248382v2

Comment: What models? Why is the answer interesting? Is there an implication that the trend observed should be surprising?

Comment: @BryanKrause: I'm simply asking if it is surprising or not. How can you answer that without any model?

Comment: I think it makes more sense to compare the current numbers to rates of vaccine "skepticism"/complacency than to worry about what models predict for the rates. If you had a particular model in mind then the question might make more sense but when you just say "with some models' expectation" it doesn't seem very meaningful, especially when the data are already in front of you.

Comment: Thanks for the edits. Is the question now "Do models of vaccination based on personal risk estimates from disease prevalence predict the decrease in vaccination over the past two weeks?"